# Microsoft Onenote collapse all sections

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

When I open a Onenote App on windows 10, 13 sections are opened and remaining sessions are collapsed. I would like all of them to be closed /collapsed except the one I am working on. So only one open and rest closed. Is it possible?

Comment: Try the advice on the last entry of [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f41ce919-ead7-4760-b052-a54895778924/onenote-2010-anyway-to-collapse-everything-section-groupsall-notebooks8?forum=officeitproprevious).

Comment: There is no collapse button as they say.

Comment: Did you look at *the last entry*?

Comment: yes #6 does not work , also that question answers pages and mine is about sections.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing for anyone that stumbled across this old thread. To collapse a bulleted or numbered list, click the first item (which should cause all items at that level to be highlighted). Then, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.